# Vague error when updating from EE 1 to EE 2 "The update script failed without returning an error."

Tags: upgrade, ee2-upgrades

When I run the update I get this error that fails as soon as it gets to 2.0.0. The script stops when it gets to updating the exp_comments table. I tried setting $conf['allow_extensions'] = "n"; before running the update but that didn't do anything.

I successfully updated from EE 1.6 to 1.7.3 first, now the version that I am updating from is EE 1.7.3

[image: Image of error screen]

Comment: Maybe try updating to a previous version of EE. For example 2.6 or before. Then go to 2.7.3 (I know, double work but, getting to 2.x.x is the important part; then go up from there.)

Comment: Nate, I tried updating to 2.3 first but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to update 1 before upgrading to 2, that's some Cargo Cult voodoo.

That error is specific to the installer attempting to run third_party update routines (often). Temporally remove third_party and try the installer again.

Comment: I didn't think updating 1 to 173 would make any difference but I was just trying everything that I could think of.

How would you recommend removing third_party? EE1 doesn't have a "third_party" folder. Is there a config override that I should put in the config.php before running the update??